Trying to clone image with transparent background won't work
I have a problem when trying to clone a png image with no background in the texture paint section.
I select the image in the clone tool but when I start cloning it, the transparent background turns white, painting my texture white.
Any idea how I can fix this?
Edit: Here is the PNG image I want to clone, with a transparent background:

But when I try to clone it into my texture, the transparent parts turn to white.


I’m not sure if that’s supposed to happen or not, I would guess it wasn’t, but there might be a tool option somewhere. Meanwhile, I strongly recommend you using an external image editor instead such as GIMP.

For those wondering, here is The Blender Manual page with entry on said Clone tool: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/texture_paint/tools.html It doesn’t seem to specify if this should be happening or if it can be disabled.

Can you post a picture or two of the workspace so we can see what you are working with? I am trying to imagine what it is you are doing and can't replicate here properly without knowing what is involved like image texture slots, cloning to the same texture, etc.

You are using the Clone tool, but you should have your image texture loading in the brush of the Draw tool and set to Stencil using pure white for your brush color so that the color of your image stencil applies as it is originally. In the texture settings of the Brush texture, it should already be set to 'Use Alpha'.
Once loaded as your Brush Texture, you can set it to 'Stencil' mapping in the Tool Settings and then move it in place with rmb. You may need to reset your aspect ratio in tool settings if it isn't meant to be square.
Happy Painting!

I had already addressed the way this legacy behavior in the 2d Image Editor Clone Tool was hacky and needing to be replaced with the same behavior of the 3d view here: https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/mMdbbc/ I am hopeful eventually someone will find a way to give us a Clone Tool in the 2D Image Editor that does the same as the Healing Brush effect we have in the 3D View.
